# Why jquery is saying missing : after property id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote follwing jquery code for slider toggle box. When i execute it, jquery saying  missing : after property id.

```
function toggleBox(){
     $(".toggleLink").toggle(                                         
           function() {
                $(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.toggleBox').slideUp('slow');
                var SlideStatus = $(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text(); 
                $.get(window.location ,{ $(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text() : SlideStatus} );
                console.log($(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text()); 
                }, function() {
                $(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.toggleBox').slideDown('slow');
                $.get(window.location ,{ SlideStatus : null } );
             });  
}
```

Where i am doing wrong. Help will be greatly apprciated

Comment: The first `$.get` is illegal syntax and does not make sense.

Comment: Could it be that your `$.get` parameters look to be the wrong way round? Try swapping `$(this).parent(etc.)` and `SlideStatus`...

Comment: the content of the of the variable SlideStatus is some number(eg:8,10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the associative array notation for objects if you want dynamic key names

```
var myobject = {};
myobject[SlideStatus] = SlideStatus;
$.get(window.location, myobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `$.get` statement doesn't make sense. You're assigning the value of `$(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text()` to the variable `SlideStatus`, then passing the same variable name to the `$.get` statement.

Either use a different variable name outside the `$.get` call, or change the name of the argument you're passing in to the `$.get` call. At the moment, they're the wrong way round (it should be `propertyName : propertyValue`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i want as PropertyNmae : propertyvalue shoud be same

Comment: So you want `$.get(window.location, {SlideStatus: SlideStatus});` ?

Comment: The problem is that you're assigning SlideStatus a value. Let's assume the value of `$(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text()` is "test text!". what you're sending to the `$.get` function is `test text! : test text!`. Try giving your outer variable (`var SlideStatus`) a different name (e.g. `var myStatus`) and pass it like this: `SlideStatus : myStatus`.

Comment: @devnull69 exactly , when i put like above it is taking ParameterName as it is i mean as sliderStatus not with dynamic value

Comment: OR you could put the `var SlideStatus` declaration in a conditional: `if(!SlideStatus){ SlideStatus = $(this).parent('.toggleBoxContainer').find('.hiddenFilterID').text(); }`.

Comment: If you want dynamic key name, you'll have to use the associative array notation `var myObjekt[key] = "value"`